# Need to Compare DataFrames in Pandas using < and > operators for specific data in a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to compare the following dataframes:
I have a pair of Z Scores with a specific ENST number here :

```
Z_SCORE_Raw

ENST00000547849 ENST00000587894
0   -1.3099506  21.56600492
```

I have to compare each of these numbers to their corresponding ENST code in this dataFrame:

```
df_new

ENST00000547849High_Avg ENST00000587894 High_Avg     
                                                       ENST00000547849 Low_Avg ENST00000587894 Low_Avg
    0.0026421609368421000   -0.0457525087368421     
                                                        -0.040015074588235300   -0.04140853107142860
```

I am given the following formula:
if Z_Score[given ENSTCode] > Avg_High[ENSTCode]
return 1
elif Z_Score[given ENSTCode] > Avg_Low[ENSTCode]
return 0
Elif Avg_High>Z_Score>AVg_Low
return 0.5

I currently have the following code to gather the correct ENST code and compare that ZScore to the corresponding High and Low average of each ENST Code:

```
for x in Z_score_raw:
        if Z_score_raw[x].any() > df_new[x + ' High_Avg'].any():
            print('1')
        elif Z_score_raw[x].any() < df_new[x + ' Low_Avg'].any():
            print('0')
        elif df_new[x + ' High_Avg'].any() > Z_score_raw[x].any() > df_new[x + ' Low_Avg']:
            print('0.5')
```

The expected output would be for

```
ENST00000547849: 0 (as -1.309 < -0.0400150745882353)
ENST00000587894: 1 (as 21.56600492 > -0.45725)
```

My current code gives me no results and skips by all of the checks.  How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: would you be able to provide the dataframes in question as dictionaries? It's easier to work on your problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you are iterating correctly, but then you are comparing a boolean value that is returned by .any() using > or <.
What is True > False or True < True?

So that doesn't make sense.

If you only have one value per column, just use [0] to select the value at the index 0.

Also, Make sure your column naming pattern is consistent (e.g. no spaces everywhere).

Your Example:
ENST00000547849High_Avg ENST00000587894 High_Avg
My Correction (no Space):
ENST00000547849High_Avg ENST00000587894High_Avg

This will provide your desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"ENST00000547849": [-1.3099506], "ENST00000587894": [21.56600492]}
d_2 = {"ENST00000547849High_Avg": [0.0026421609368421000], "ENST00000587894High_Avg" : [-0.0457525087368421], "ENST00000547849Low_Avg" : [-0.040015074588235300], "ENST00000587894Low_Avg": [-0.04140853107142860]}

Z_score_raw = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data = d_2)

for x in Z_score_raw:
    if Z_score_raw[x][0] > df_new[x + 'High_Avg'][0]:
        print(f"{x}: 1")
    elif Z_score_raw[x][0] < df_new[x + 'Low_Avg'][0]:
        print(f"{x}: 0")
    elif df_new[x + 'High_Avg'][0] > Z_score_raw[x][0] > df_new[x + 'Low_Avg'][0]:
        print(f"{x}: 0.5")
```

Output:

ENST00000547849: 0

ENST00000587894: 1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, When i put in the [0] for the index, I get the following error: alueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().  Which is why i ended up putting .any()

Comment: i forgot the last [0] in the last elif. Can you try again please?
df_new[x + 'Low_Avg'] was selecting the series
now df_new[x + 'Low_Avg'][0] selects the value at index 0

Comment: yes, I actually have a different dataframe than I provided, which contains NaN characters, So i removed those characters and used what you provided and it worked! Thank you very much!